# Удаленный доступ к linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-access

я новичок в linux и мне нужно удаленно подключиться к ферме на ubuntu 18.04 TLS. О варианте с приобретением белого ip знаю, но все же хочу узнать, есть ли бесплатные способы установить стабильное удаленное соединение на linux, тк ставить буду на ферму к которой не буду иметь физического доступа долгое время. Интересуют способы как подключиться и с другого linux, и с windows 8/10. Спасибо!

Comment: Есть один способ, как удаленно к ферме подключаться... О нем мало кто знает, поэтому скажу по секрету: teamviewer.

Answer (score 3):

Если оператор выдаёт белый динамический адрес, то dynamic dns + cron-скрипт на сервере для обновления записи на DynDNS.
Если оператор не выдаёт белый адрес, а предоставляет доступ в интернет через NAT, то Remote Port Forwarding SSH Tunnel на/с сервер(а) с белым IP. Как-то так:

Remote Port Forwarding SSH Tunnel (port ABCD):
    UbuntuServer -> (Operator->NAT) -> Internet Server

```
ssh -R ABCD:localhost:10022 user@internet.server
```

Client (другой Linux / Windows)

```
ssh user@internet.server:ABCD   // эта ssh-сессия будет проброшена на UbuntuServer:10022
```

При этом SSH-сервер, к которому нужен доступ, должен слушать порт 10022.

---

Дополняю ответ насчёт SSH Remote Port Forwarding.

Т.к. remote port forward сессия может обрываться/подвисать, надо а) настроить таймауты для SSH и б) при необходимости перезапускать эту сессию.

Для этого делаем:

1. скрипт для (пере)запуска RemotePortForwarding-туннеля (для основного Ubuntu-сервера) - скажем, /opt/scripts/sshtunn.sh:

(апостроф в начале первой строки не нужен)

`` '#!/usr/bin/env bash
    CMD="ssh -f -N tunnel"
    PID=`pgrep -f "$CMD"`
    if [ -z "$PID" ]; then
        $CMD
        echo "[$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] SSH tunnel (re)start" >> /tmp/ssh.tunnel.log
    fi ``

2. исполняет его cron; для этого в /etc/cron.d нужно положить такой файлик:
   (< user > - имя пользователя, под которым запускать скрипт)

`* * * * * <user> /opt/scripts/sshtunn.sh`

3. Чтобы скрипт нормально сработал (а также, чтобы сессия не подвисала), должна быть соответствующая настройка в ~/.ssh/config (в домашней директории того самого пользователя, под которым запускается скрипт):

   `host tunnel
   hostname <internet.server.ip.or.fqdn>
   user     <internet.server.user>
   port     22
   identityfile ~/.ssh/keys/tunnel.key
   RemoteForward 10222 127.0.0.1:22
   TCPKeepAlive yes
   ServerAliveInterval 10
   ServerAliveCountMax 6`
4. ну и тот самый интернет-сервер должен принимать подключения по ключу ~/.ssh/keys/tunnel.key

Comment: Только вот первую команду ещё нужно будет как-то регулярно набирать, а без физического доступа это проблематично. Здесь направшивается или автозапуск/перезапуск и заранее прописанными ssh-ключами, или что-то ещё

Comment: Вообще, при сбоях интернета первая команда рискует навечно повиснуть и лишить связи, так что нужно ещё таймауты в настройках ssh настроить (лично у меня почему-то не получалось и всё равно висло навечно даже с таймаутами), так что сомневаюсь в надёжности такого решения

Comment: ну cron-скрипт же и наберёт регулярно, если SSH-сессия отвалится; ну да -  доступ по SSH-ключам; у меня так работает (при отвале основного канала, который с белым IP, хожу через вот такой "огород over LTE"); ну и, если есть желание повышать надёжность и улучшать импрувность, можно копать в сторону autossh и иже с ним (хотя, примерно те же яйца)

Comment: У вас видимо «орогод» ещё не отваливался) А у меня вот отваливался — `ssh -R` при этом виснет, не принимает никаких подключений, и его кто-то должен вырубить и запустить заново. Но удалённого доступа нет, потому что `ssh -R` завис, поэтому перезапустить некому. Cron-скрипт не сможет вырубить его, потому что он не знает, что `ssh -R` завис.

Comment: у меня, видимо, какой-то не такой SSH :) а по-существу - в настройках ssh/sshd есть же параметры Server/Client KeepAlive и т.д. - один раз настроить и долго радоваться жизни.

Comment: Я их настраивал, но почему-то всё равно зависало. А вообще я к тому, что это всё должно быть явно упомянуто в тексте ответа, чтобы ни автор вопроса, ни другие читатели не забыли об этом

Comment: резонно, но многобуков :) тогда уже надо сюда учебник по SSH / Bash / и лёгкий ликбез про сети подтягивать

Comment: @andreymal, посмотрел конфиг, видимо, ещё "TCPKeepAlive yes" нужен, чтобы не зависал ssh -R